# Are question/answer bans implemented in Stack Exchange 2.0 sites?

Tags: support, post-ban

I always thought question/answer bans were present on Stack Overflow (and maybe in all the trilogy sites). I was recently chatting with a user, and he said there are answer bans on other sites as well.

Are question/answer bans present in other sites, outside the trilogy ones? I mean, are they present in all the Stack Exchange 2.0 sites, or are they enabled in those sites that need post-bans because low quality contributions (or other reasons)?

Comment: Programmers and MSO are the only sites outside the trilogy that have post bans (afaik).

Comment: The ban rules are relaxed on MSO, since downvotes are very common here.

Comment: It's not a duplicate: The other question is asking to point out issues or problems.

Comment: _Feel free to post questions or concerns here._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As of quite recently, [quality blocks are fully in play on all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291142/295684). They come with all the normal warnings and rolling rate limits.